# VTT output for Azure Transcription JSON file

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I looked up and found this - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/captioning-concepts?pivots=programming-language-javascript

In Caption output format section, it says -

> The Speech service supports output formats such as SRT (SubRip Text) and WebVTT (Web Video Text Tracks).

But there is no option to set output format in API reference - https://eastus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/speech-to-text-api-v3-0/operations/CreateTranscription

I am using Create Transcription API to send video/audio files > 30 minutes and Azure gives transcription result in JSON like following -

https://spsvcprodeus.blob.core.windows.net/bestor-c6e3ae79-1b48-41bf-92ff-940bea3e5c2d/TranscriptionData/1a7f53a1-b254-4edc-a03a-20aa926423b7_0_0.json?sv=2021-08-06&st=2022-11-09T19%3A05%3A26Z&se=2022-11-10T07%3A10%3A26Z&sr=b&sp=rl&sig=4g80znxLM%2FVhCJI7iJLNETGd%2B%2B442eubSOQikjQpvZU%3D

I'm planning to write a script to convert transcription JSON to VTT, but it will be really helpful if that is already there or something I can request as output format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The speech key needs to be retrieved to make it work. Create the speech service in azure portal and get the supportive python code to convert speech to text.

[image]

[image]

Get the python code ([captioning](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/master/scenarios/python/console/captioning/captioning.py)) to speech to text.

To set the environment:

```
setx SPEECH_KEY your-key
```

Create caption from the speech

Go to the same directory where the code was available.

```
pip install azure-cognitiveservices-speech
```

**Run the application:**

python captioning.py --input caption.this.mp4 --format any --output caption.output.txt --srt --realTime --threshold 5 --delay 0 --profanity mask --phrases "Contoso;Jessie;Rehaan"

To check for the SRT format -> [Link](https://docs.fileformat.com/video/srt/)

[image]

We have the duration limit for every service in azure. Check for the quota and support with the [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/speech-services-quotas-and-limits#text-to-speech-quotas-and-limits-per-speech-resource).

Comment: I ended up writing script to convert JSON to VTT but this should be the proper way haha. Hope your answer helps someone looking for the same solution in future. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the azure batch api, it seems to only return in json format. This [library](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk/blob/db4a5a9a4a152e86348f3c016ac0b0cf3b539cf7/scenarios/python/console/captioning/caption_helper.py#L19) might help